# How to initialize another key's value if one key is missing in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I have one requirement to initialize another key's value if one key is missing in application.properties.

For example, I have two keys abc and xyz, wherein only one will be found in application.properties.

But there's another utility that will write the key and values to the application.properties before my springboot application comes up.

So I need to read the keys accordingly.

Is there a way to read the values from application.properties, such that if abc exists, the value of abc to be read,  or otherwise xyz.

But I need to read the values into the same java variable, of whatever key exists in application.properties.

any leads will be highly appreciated.

My Code:

```
public class Sample {
    public static Integer CONNECT_INACTIVITY_TIME_LIMIT;
    public static Integer MAX_NUM_CONNECTION;       

    @Value("${accessKey.connectionTimeInactivityLimit}")
    public void setConnectTimeLimit(Integer CONNECT_INACTIVE_TIME_LIMIT) {
        Sample.CONNECT_INACTIVITY_TIME_LIMIT = CONNECT_INACTIVE_TIME_LIMIT;
    }

    @Value("${accessKey.maxConnectionNumber}")
    public void setMaxConnectionNumber(Integer MAX_NUM_CONNECTION) {
        Sample.MAX_NUM_CONNECTION = MAX_NUM_CONNECTION;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `@Value` and chain the expressions `@Value("${abc:${xyzzy}}")` something like that should work.

Comment: @M.Deinum It is not working. It is giving me error: `@Value("${server.port:${secure.port}}") private String securedPort; Error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'secure.port' in value "server.port:${secure.port}"`

Comment: You need an empty value after the last placeholder `@Value("${server.port:${secure.port:}}"`

Comment: It worked like charm @M.Deinum. Thank you so much. Pease post this as answer. I'll accept.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
@Value("${accessKey.connectionTimeInactivityLimit:${accessKey.maxConnectionNumber}}")
```

If the first property doesn't exist then the value will be assigned using the second one.

Comment: have you tried this? first time I see this kind of construction

Comment: This is SPEL(Spring Expression Language),you can see the doc[SPEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions)

Comment: It is giving me an error. `@Value("${server.port:${secure.port}}")
 private String securedPort;` Error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'secure.port' in value "server.port:${secure.port}"

Comment: @Abhishek seems like both `server.port` and `secure.port` properties do not exist. You need to specify at least one.

Comment: @M.Czerwinski I have server.port defined but not secure.port. This isn't working

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;    

@Value("${accessKey.connectionTimeInactivityLimit}")
public void setConnectTimeLimit(Integer CONNECT_INACTIVE_TIME_LIMIT) {
    if (env.getProperty("JaccessKey.maxConnectionNumber") != null) {
       Sample.CONNECT_INACTIVITY_TIME_LIMIT = env.getProperty("JaccessKey.maxConnectionNumber");
    } 
    Sample.CONNECT_INACTIVITY_TIME_LIMIT = CONNECT_INACTIVE_TIME_LIMIT;
}
```